# can't download image from web and how to check image from web

Tags: objective-c, networking

So I have this method to download an image from imgur.com as shown below:

```
- (void)getImageForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"i.imgur.com/%@.jpg",
                                     [self.IDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    self.imageTest = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
}
```

and then log the size of the data with this:

```
NSLog(@"%lx", (unsigned long)imageData.length);
```

but the size of the image in the log says

0

previously I use this asynchronous method:

```
- (void)getImageForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"i.imgur.com/%@.jpg",
                                     [self.IDArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                       queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        UIImage *imageMain = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        self.imageTest = [[UIImage alloc] init];
        self.imageTest = [self imageWithImage:imageMain forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }];
    self.imageTest = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
}
```

but the log also says 0

yes the url exist. I have log it in another another method it is: i.imgur.com/EXtwoxT

What did I do wrong? how do I check that the image has been downloaded properly?

Comment: Can you log the data length inside your completionHandler?
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
}

Comment: yes I log the data size inside the completion handler, it just says 0

Comment: What is the response status code?